# How to get back to the top of 'main' after executing a void outside 'main'

Tags: c

How is it possible to get back to the top of the `main` after fully executing a function?

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  // GET BACK TO HERE AFTER EXECUTING "FUNCTION();"
  printf("Something here\n");
  printf("Something here\n");
  printf("Something here\n");
  printf("Something here\n");
  printf("Something here\n");
  function();
}

function(){

}
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop.

Comment: @dbush sorry, I'm new. Can you elaborate more? I would appreciate it.

Comment: `while (condition_is_true) { /* Do stuff */ }`.

Comment: Did the answers so far work well, or do you need any more help? I'd be more than happy to walk through it :)

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon Yes! They helped me :) Thank you very much, I really appreciate it

Comment: Sure thing! Starting programming is super daunting, but you're in for a wild ride :) Good luck out there!

Comment: Thanks a lot @EnigmaticBacon ! Hope this journey does not end up being painful, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  bool keep_going = true;
  while (keep_going) {
    // Your main() code here.
    function();
    // Don't forget to set keep_going to false at some point so the program terminated.
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The above construct is a while loop. It keeps executing the loop body (between the braces) until the condition at the beginning of the loop is false.

**Do not use goto.** Goto, while it works, is generally considered an "evil" construct like macros as they make it harder to keep track of program flow and generally leads to spaghetti code. A while loop works perfectly fine here and is considered good programming style.

To be clear, `goto` (like macros) exists because it is useful in *some* cases. But those cases do not occur often, and by labeling them as "evil", one understands that one should avoid using that feature if better alternatives (like loops) exist.